# Hibernate orm for a view

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

How do you ORM a view?

Is there any difference with a table in terms of reverse engineering?

In my case, I have a whole pile of joined tables that will be read-only in an application.

So, if I need sort of an Object with all collections in proper order, instead of long
chains of relationships - collection with another etc, it'll be simpler.

What do you think and how do you accomplish this?

Comment: Come again? It might just be me, but I have *no idea* what you are asking :)

Comment: @Jørn Schou-Rode It's fairly simple. Usually you map tables. You can map a view. First I ask how you map a view and second I ask is it a good idea for read-only data.

Comment: Please edit your question directly if you want to refine it and make it easier to understand.

Comment: I am sorry about that. It really was just me misintepreting the word "view" as something application specific. After an extra cup of coffee, I have read your question again, and it makes much more sense now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html): "There is no difference between a view and a base table for a Hibernate mapping." To map a view, in your orm.xml file you would simply need `table = [your view name]`.

This is, incidentally, an artifact of the SQL standard that defines a view as a type of table, so they should operate just like a table (though many SQL vendors to not properly support INSERT and UPDATE on views). This means the same feature is likely to be supported by other ORM vendors.

As for whether or not it's a good idea, if you're already creating an ORM mapping for the raw tables, I would do as BalusC suggests (since you wouldn't need to create a object just to access a view). If the data is not being generated by your application so you don't already have an ORM mapping defined and you only need to access the view rather than the tables that compose the view, there's no reason not to just map the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just obtain it as a collection of (nested) beans the usual Hibernate/DAO way, put it (in a bean?) in the request scope and let an iterating tag in the view layer iterate over it and use EL to display it. In JSTL for example you can use `<c:forEach>` to iterate over a (nested) collection.